# Spring 3 -- accessing Model values in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, spring-3, modelattribute

I have a JSP where I am trying to print out values from my Model, but nothing appears in the place where I refer to those values.  Here is the controller method where I set the values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poll1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPoll1(@RequestParam String vote,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = poll1DAO.tallyVote(vote);
    Cookie poll1 = new Cookie("poll1", "voted");
    model.addAttribute("poll1Yes", resultMap.get("yes").toString());
    model.addAttribute("poll1No", resultMap.get("no").toString());
    poll1.setMaxAge(maxSeconds);
    response.addCookie(poll1);
    return "redirect:/polls";
}
```

Here is the part of the JSP where I refer to the Model attributes.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b><i>Poll #1 -- </i></b>Would you like to have a 30-year reunion in 2016?<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;<c:out value='${model.poll1Yes}' /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>No</b></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;<c:out value='${model.poll1No}' /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my output.  Instead of actual values, nothing is printed out in the attributes' places.

```
Poll #1 -- Would you like to have a 30-year reunion in 2016?

Yes  – 

No  –
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to reference `model` in your JSP.

```
<c:out value='${poll1Yes}' />
<c:out value='${poll1No}' />
```

Comment: What if we want to access a dynamic object from the model, is there a way to do something like `model["poll" + num + "yes"]` ?